# React Native RCTFatal + 448 crash when testing via iOS TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight, bugsnag

I have released my React Native App on IOS TestFlight for few weeks, everything looks good except the App will crash sometimes (Launch screen will show up about 1 sec, then App crashes). And once the crash starts, reopen the App will crash it again.

I looked up my crashes log in Xcode, the error is `RCTFatal + 448 (RCTAssert.m:132)` caused by `main + 88 (main.m:14)`[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iLHr.png).

I'm certain the App is in `Release` mode; I can't replicate the crash on Simulator; I installed [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native-error-reporting/), No error was reported; I have the `componentDidCatch` Error Boundary in my `index.js`, No error was caught, so I guess the error in not from my JavaScript code?

Has anyone experienced the similar issue and figured it out? Here's my crash log and `package.json` in case it helps

```
Date/Time:           2019-03-11 19:39:06.1522 +1000
Launch Time:         2019-03-11 19:39:05.6004 +1000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)
Baseband Version:    3.31.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x211811ea4 __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:172)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x2109e1a50 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:557)
2   App                             0x104b475f8 RCTFatal + 448 (RCTAssert.m:132)
3   App                             0x104ba2da0 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 712 (RCTNativeModule.mm:116)
4   App                             0x104ba292c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dy... + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:71)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x2112496c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1372)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x21124a484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:511)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x211229b34 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 1012 (inline_internal.h:2441)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2117a1ce4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1813)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x21179cbac __CFRunLoopRun + 1964 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x21179c0e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
11  GraphicsServices                0x213a15584 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
12  UIKitCore                       0x23eb30c00 UIApplicationMain + 212 (UIApplication.m:4347)
13  App                             0x104aed3b4 main + 88 (main.m:14)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x21125abb4 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002113a7104 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211427948 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 296 (pthread.c:1492)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000002112fed78 abort + 140 (abort.c:94)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000002109c8f78 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:75)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000002109c9120 default_terminate_handler() + 304 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:68)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000002109e1e58 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:693)
6   App                             0x0000000104d37470 CPPExceptionTerminate() + 520 (BSG_KSCrashSentry_CPPException.mm:193)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000002109d50fc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000002109d5188 std::terminate() + 84 (cxa_handlers.cpp:97)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000021124a498 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:514)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000211229b34 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 1012 (inline_internal.h:2441)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000002117a1ce4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1813)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000021179cbac __CFRunLoopRun + 1964 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000021179c0e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
14  GraphicsServices                0x0000000213a15584 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000023eb30c00 UIApplicationMain + 212 (UIApplication.m:4347)
16  App                             0x0000000104aed3b4 main + 88 (main.m:14)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000021125abb4 start + 4
```

---

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.1.4",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.24",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.0.3",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.3.5",
    "apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.3",
    "apollo-link-http-common": "^0.2.5",
    "apollo-link-state": "^0.4.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.17",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.0.5",
    "aws-appsync": "^1.3.4",
    "aws-appsync-react": "^1.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.15.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native": "0.57.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.24.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-heic-converter": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.0",
    "react-native-open-settings": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-quick-actions": "^0.3.7",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.13",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.15",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that Bugsnag is not reporting the error when the app crashes so I suspect Bugsnag may be misconfigured.

Have you followed the instructions here to ensure that native crashes are captured?
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/enhanced-native-integration/

If you reach out to us directly at Bugsnag Support we can take a closer look.

Comment: I do have my API key set in `Info.plist` and `[BugsnagReactNative start]` added in `AppDelegate.m`. Just wondering, is there anyway I can manually trigger the native crashes so I can make sure my Bugsnag config is right?